# Autoload helpers functions directory in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've a class with a bunch of Date Helpers functions in it. I stored it at app\Helpers\DateHelper.php

## Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DateTime;

class DateHelper {

    public static function day_ago($date) {

        if ($date) {

            $ts = time() - strtotime(str_replace("-","/", $date ));

            if($ts>31536000) $val = round($ts/31536000,0).' year';
            else if($ts>2419200) $val = round($ts/2419200,0).' month';
            else if($ts>604800) $val = round($ts/604800,0).' week';
            else if($ts>86400) $val = round($ts/86400,0).' day';
            else if($ts>3600) $val = round($ts/3600,0).' hour';
            else if($ts>60) $val = round($ts/60,0).' minute';
            else $val = $ts.' second';

            if($val>1) $val .= 's';

            return $val;


        }

    }

}
```

---

## Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Helpers"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Helper.php"]
},
```

Then, I `run composer install`

I got

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
```

---

## Alias

Then, I added to the alias array like this:

```
'DateHelper'  => 'app\Helpers\DateHelper',
```

---

## Use

Then, I used it:

```
{{ DateHelper::day_ago($n->created_at) }}
```

---

## Result

Now, I keep getting `Class 'DateHelper' not found`.

How do I properly add it ?

Comment: do a `composer dump-autoload`. And just call `day_ago($n->created_at);`

Comment: Let me try, I thought `composer install` include that already.

Comment: But in this case, you don't have to create a date helper function. Why don't you use `Carbon` ?

Comment: I have other functions that I would like to make a use out of it. So eventually, I need to learn how to integrate a helpers function in my L5 application.

Comment: Sure, so whenever you create a helper class, just include the path in the `composer.json` and do `composer dump-autoload`. Then you don't have to reference the class again.

Comment: I did that, and I ran `composer dump-autoload` I got the same result. Did I call it wrong ?

Comment: Try to follow the following steps.

Comment: You don't have to create any namespace or not even a class. Just a file with all the functions as shown below.

Comment: The Laravel way would be to have a `ServiceProvider` responsible for loading the helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your alias is wrong.  The alias is meant to be the fully qualified class name with namespace, not the directory it's in.

```
'DateHelper'  => 'App\DateHelper',
```

I would suggest following PSR-4 standards.  It would save time and minimize confusion.

Additionally, so this doesn't happen again, it would be better to use syntax like the following...

```
'DateHelper'  => App\DateHelper::class,
```

That way, you can be absolutely sure the class exists.

Comment: Ok. So how do we make our directory full of helpers classes auto load ?

Comment: Set the correct namespaces on them.  For example, your `DateHelper` should have the namespace `App\Helpers`.  If your namespaces follow the directory structure, PSR-4 will autoload them with no changes required to `composer.json` and no need to `composer dump-autoload`.  Keep in mind if you change the namespace though, make sure to update the alias to reflect the change in namespace.

Answer (score 1):

A typical example for a helper file in Laravel:

1. Create a `helper.php` file in your `app` directory.
2. Create your helper functions
3. Now add the `helper.php` file in your `composer.json` file.
4. Do a `composer dump-autoload`
5. Now your helper function will be available throughout your project.

If you are creating a directory for the helper files, then namespace the helperfiles.

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
     "database",
   ],
   "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Helpers\\": "app/helpers/" //This is if you are using the directory
   },
   "files": ["helper.php"] //This is if it's just a php file.
},
```

i.e :

```
//app/helpers/helperClass.php
<?php namespace Helpers;

class helperClass{
  public function showDate()
  {
    //return
  }
}
```

In your controller, when you use the helper function, import the class.

i.e:

```
use Helpers/helperClass;
//If you've creates an alias for this, use it here. 
use helperClass;   //(This is from the config/app.php file)
```

If it's a view, use it like: `{{ \Helpers\helperClass::showDate() }}`

Comment: I know that steps will work because I've done that. My goal is to autoload the whole directory not just 1 file which is helper.php.

Comment: You can include `"Helpers": "app/helpers"` directory in your `psr-4` section of the `composer.json` and namespace your helper files with `Helpers`. Also do a `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Ohh `psr-4`, I thought it was `classmap` section. I'll change it and update you.

Comment: Here my autoload section, `"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "app/Helpers"
        },
        "files": ["app/Helper.php"]
    },`

Comment: Also, if you are making your helper functions inside a class, make an alias in the `config` file and reference the class whereever you use it.

Comment: No no, not like that. I'll update the answer. For some weird reason, I'm not able to style the code. But anyway I'll try.

Comment: What is my alias should look like ?

Comment: `'DateHelper'  => 'app\Helpers\DateHelper'` ?

Comment: Is there anyway, to shortening out my namespace in my view to just `{{helperClass::showDate() }}` ? This `{{ \Helpers\helperClass::showDate() }}` is quite long.

Comment: Yes, you can do that by creating an alias in the `config/app.php` file. In the `aliases` section, add: `'helperClass' => Helpers\helperClass::class,`

Comment: Then do a `composer dump-autoload` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have `'DateHelper'  => App\Helpers\DateHelper::class,` , Then, `composer dump-autoload`, Then I called it like `{{ DateHelper::day($n->created_at) }}` , result, `Class 'DateHelper' not found`

Comment: If I called it like this `{{ App\Helpers\DateHelper::day($n->created_at) }}` , it works.

Comment: I feel that my alias, never get set - for some wired reasons.

Comment: Don't use `App\Helpers\DateHelper::class`. If you've included the `Helpers` directory in psr-4, just use `Helpers\DateHelper::class`.

Comment: Ohh ... let me adjust that. Sorry.

Comment: Try `'DateHelper'  => Helpers\DateHelper::class,`, and call `{{ DateHelper::day($n->created_at) }}` get `Class 'DateHelper' not found`

Comment: You might still have to use `{{ \DateHelper::day()}}`

Comment: If you really want to clean your helper function call, avoid classes. Just use  functions. Just like laravel helper functions `{{ url() }}`